# How can I prove that for any $n \ge 4$, $2^n \ge n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that for any $n \ge 4$, $2^n \ge n^2$

So far I have the following but have hit a blank on the next steps. (hopefully what I have is correct)

**Base Case**: 
n = 4
2<sup>4</sup> ≥ 4<sup>2</sup> = 16 ≥ 16 
since 16 = 16 the base case is true

**Inductive Step:** 
Assume: 2<sup>k</sup> ≥ k<sup>2</sup>
Prove: 2<sup>(k+1)</sup> ≥ (k+1)<sup>2</sup>

I am a bit confused since all the proofs we have done thus far have been prove that something = something. And I adjust one side to = the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $2^k\geq k^2$. Then $2^{k+1}\geq 2k^2$. If you can show $2k^2\geq (k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$ for $k\geq 4$, you are done. $2k^2\geq k^2+2k+1$ iff $0\geq -k^2+2k+1$, which is true for $k\geq 4$ (parabola opening downward with largest root $<4$).

Comment: That helped! Thanks!

Comment: $-k^2 +2k +1\le 0\implies k^2 -2k -1\ge 0\implies k= \frac{2\pm \sqrt{8}}{2}= 1 \pm \sqrt{2}\implies (k-2.414)(k+0.414)\ge 0\implies (f_1)(f_2)\ge 0$. If $k\gt 2.414, f_1, f_2\gt 0$, else if $k\lt -0.414$, product $\gt 0$. Between these values, expression $k^2 -2k -1 \le 0$, else not. Say, for $k=3, 9-6-1=2 \gt 0; k=1, 1-2-1\lt 0; k=2, -1\lt 0;  k=-0.5, 0.25\gt 0$. Similarly, for $-k^2 +2k +1\le 0$ need values of $k$ in interval $ (-0.414, 2.414)$ to have -ve values. Sorry, do not see $k=4$ as of significance. Also, the curve changes sign (slope) at two values, so do not see parabola too.

Comment: The thing that you wanted to show was if $k \ge 4$ then $2k^2 \ge (k+1)^2$. If we know that $k \ge 2.414$, then $2k^2 \ge (k+1)^2$, then clearly we have $k \ge 4$, then $2k^2 \le (k+1)^2$. OP was referring to the parabola $f(k)=-k^2+2k+1$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thanks a lot, but even $k\ge 2.414$ (or, if taking integer values; then $k\ge 3$) would have been enough. As then, $2.9 \ge (4)^2 \implies 18 \ge 16$ also. Seems missing sthg. Drew in desmos: $-x^2 +2x +1$, and $x=4$ was not relevant there too. However, my statement for not seeing a parabola in last comment was wrong, it just shows area of parabola above $x$- axis between two points. $-k^2 +2k+1 \le 0$ has negative values in the region outside the two values, as multiply $k^2 -2k-1 \ge 0$ by $-1$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please respond to my last comment.

Comment: To avoid long comment threads, I will meet you on chat.

Answer (score 1):

For your base case, you should specify what $k$ is, for it could be an arbitrary $k\in \mathbb{N}$, or it could mean that for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $1 \leq j \leq k$, which is strong induction. I'm assuming you are attempting to prove the proposition using weak induction, which would mean that $k$ is an arbitrary natural number.

The key to most inequality induction proofs is that what you are given will not be enough on its own to demonstrate some proposition. We may need to think of extending the inequalities to include compound inequalities in order to obtain what we need.

**Induction Hypothesis**: Suppose for an arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $2^k \geq k^2$.

We know that $k^2 \leq k^2 + 2k + 1 = (k+1)^2$, since $k > 0$. By the induction hypothesis, we know that $k^2 \leq 2^k$, which means

$$k^2 \leq (k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 \leq 2^k + 2k + 1 \tag{1}$$

(Observe that given $n^2 \leq 2^n$, we just added the expression $2n + 1$ to both sides of the inequality and formed the compound inequality $(1)$).

Now observe that $2k+1 \leq 2^k$. This is clearly true because $2k+1$ is linear while $2^k$ is exponential where $k \geq 4$. Consequently, $2^k + 2k + 1 \leq 2^k + 2^k  = 2\cdot 2^k = 2^{k+1}$. Therefore, our compound inequality becomes

$$k^2 \leq (k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 \leq 2^k + 2k + 1 \leq 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1} \tag{2}$$

From the transitive property, we deduce that

$$(k+1)^2 \leq 2^{k+1} \tag{3}$$

as desired.

Therefore, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the inequality $n^2 \leq 2^n$ is true.

$\blacksquare$