# Show using Bernoulli inequality approach (using induction, & transitivity) $2^n \ge n^2, \ \ \forall n\ge 4, n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: induction

It is given in the book by John B. Reade, titled: Introduction to Mathematical Analysis; on [pg. 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3PZS.png); to prove the inequality

$$2^n \ge n^2, \ \ \forall n\ge 4, n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

It states that has distilled the proof using induction, & transitivity to the proof for the inequality: $2n^2\ge (n+1)^2, \forall n \ge 4$.

Am confused & feel that the proof before it for showing (Bernoulli inequality) $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$, by using induction, & transitivity must be applicable. Although, not clear how. Am presenting my attempt below based on that proof, but am unable to get the *desired* form of the inequality using that.

The inequality is true for the base case: $n=(n_0=)4$, i.e. $2^4 \ge 4^2$ is true.

Assume it is true for a particular $n\gt 4$ (inductive step), need show that it implies it is also true for $n+1$.

$2^{n +1} = 2^n.2\ge (n+1)^2\implies 2^n.2\ge (n+1)^2 = 2^{(n+1)}\ge (n+1)^2$. This can't be pursued further.

2. Also, need show that $2^n.2\ge 2n^2$; but that leads to another proof using induction, & transitivity, as shown below. *(I assume that the author takes this inequality to be known, hence not elaborates it).*

For $n \ge 4, n\in \mathbb{N}$, need show $2^n.2\ge 2n^2$.
Base case $n=4: 2^4.2 \ge 2.16$.
Inductive case assumed for a value $n$.
Need show that $2^{(n+1)}.2\ge 2(n+1)^2\implies 2^{(n+1)}\ge (n+1)^2$

So, going nowhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521611/how-can-i-prove-that-for-any-n-ge-4-2n-ge-n2

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang I tried hard but could not infer anything except $\sqrt{2}n \ge (n+1)\implies \sqrt{2} \ge \frac{n}{n+1}$. Also, this expression is what want to prove above as derived finally.

Comment: @VIVID Seems to differ as no use made of $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$. But, the answers are good.

Comment: @VIVID If can show that the selected answer uses the property $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$, then proves my post too.

Comment: you mean you need a proof using that $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$?

Comment: @VIVID Yes, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, we don't really need $(1 + x)^n \ge 1+nx$ to prove that $2n^2 \ge (n+1)^2, \forall n \ge 4$.

Since it is just saying that $$n^2 \ge 2n+1, \forall n \ge 4$$

which is equivalent to $$(n-1)^2 \ge 2, \forall n \ge 4$$

which we know it is true since if $n \ge 4$, the $(n-1)^2 \ge 9 \ge 2$.

---

If we insist to use $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$, we have

$$\left( 1-\frac1n\right)^2 \ge 1-\frac2n$$

Note that for $n \ge 5$, we have $1-\frac2n \ge 1-\frac25=\frac35 \ge \frac12 $.

Hence for $n \ge 5$, we have $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2 \ge \frac12.$

which is equivalent to $$ 2(n-1)^2 \ge n^2, \forall n \ge 5$$

which is equivalent to

$$2n^2 \ge \left( 1+n\right)^2, \forall n  \ge 4.$$

Comment: Please see my comment to the selected answer in the stated duplicate post (as by @VIVID) at: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521639/424260. I hope am correct, if not point out the fallacy - here, there, or in last chatroom at: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110379/new-room-108248.

Comment: Please see my today's post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3767531/424260. It is for reason of inverse not existing, wrt a binop; yet two-sided identity existing. I mean why two-sided identity is not a sufficient condition for inverse to exist wrt a binop on a set.

Comment: Please respond to my last comment. I have stated after discussions that $x^2=e$ should be the condition, but it is NOT clear HOW is it possible for two-sided identity to exist; yet the property of $x^2=e$ not being followed.

Comment: I do not know what is your doubt, anyway, I need to go out to buy dinner before a contest in $45$ minutes.

Comment: I meant that if identity exists wrt a binop, then all non-identity elements ($x$) MUST be following the property $x^2=e$. I cannot think why this property is not being followed, yet identity exists.

Comment: Please see my edited OP.

Comment: I request an answer to the earlier stated post.

Comment: what is the question asking for? you already found the answer in a table right?

Comment: Yes, the table allowed to find out (no other commentor figured this out) that $x^2=e$ is the sufficient condition, while having double-sided identity is known a-priori as the necessary condition. But, what this lacks is that this is applicable only for groups of order $2$; as read by me on further reading. I have mentioned this in Edit $3$ in OP. I request an answer that covers order $2$ & higher order sets with binops to have condition to have inverse apart from two-sided identity.(I want to add that order of set is referring to their size in terms of no. of elements.)

Comment: i do not know the answer.

Comment: Can you please provide an incomplete answer that states my last comment here, so as to attract attention of others rather than getting deleted automatically. A new question with direct emphasis of such needed condition on sets with size $\ge 3$ is even more difficult to construct, & much more prone to negative votes.